# In Ada, specifying a Record’s Integer field as unbounded, probably box <> notation, in order to set the range when instantiating

Tags: record, ada

Using GNAT CE with Ada on Macbook Intel silicon and want to specify (.ads) a record type with a type integer field, as unbounded,in order to set the record’s internet field’s range later, probably with box <> notation. But can’t get it right:

```
type a_gear is
record
num: Integer positive range <>;  -- fails     
position: Integer range <>) of integer; -- fails
end record;
```

Comment: You might try declaring the type within a generic package and substitute the formal generic parameters for the types you want to set later.

Comment: The code you show is clearly syntactically incorrect, as you cannot use box <> in a range constraint for an integer type (except in a formal generic type, as Jim Rogers suggests). You seem to be confusing  <> as used in the declaration of an array type, for a variable index range, with the declaration of a record type. Perhaps you could explain more about what you want the record type to contain (represent), and why the range should be set "later"?

Comment: Use a discriminated record instead, setting both the discriminant and the range at the same time (when instantiating.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I wasn’t sure if if I could use the box <> in a record’s field and now know. I will try a discriminated record instead. Tks again.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you can't get it right is because it's invalid, you can't specify an anonymous subtype inline like that; the solution, therefore, is to "lift" your constraints out into a named subtype:

```
Subtype Percent is Natural range 0..100;
Type Some_Record is record
   Value : Percent;
End record;
```